# Regex MacAddress: exclude fake values

Tags: regex, mac-address

I use regex `^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$` and it works fine.

Problem is that sometimes I get fake values like: `00:00:00:00:00:00`.

I tried to search algorithms and understood, that there are no clear algo for validation. But I want to exclude explicit fake values like `00:00:00:00:00:00`, `11:11:11:11:11:11`... `99-99-99-99-99-99`

Could somebody help me with such regex, which found such values? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!(\d)(?:[:-]?\1)*$)([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3IjceO/1).

You may get rid of capturing groups using `^(?!(\d)(?:[:-]?\1)*$)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$`.

*Details*

- `^` -  start of string
- `(?!(\d)(?:[:-]?\1)*$)`
- `(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}` - five repetitions of two hex chars followed with `:` or `-`
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` - two hex chars
- `$` - end of string.